# Use each row's computed result to next row and further

Tags: sql

I have a table listed below and want to calculate new stock. initially new stock is 0

```
id  qty  price  operation  newstock
1   20   23      buy
2   10   12      sale
3   15   14      buy
4   6    13      buy
```

and so on

want output like- in case of buy- newstock+qty
and in case of sale- newstock-qty

```
id  qty  price  operation  newstock
1   20   23      buy        23    (eg- 0+23= 23)
2   10   12      sale       13    (previous row 23-10)
3   15   14      buy        28    (previous row 13+15)
4   6    13      buy        32    ( previous row 28+6)
```

I used cross apply also but not getting result.

Comment: I assume the first row should be `20`, not `23`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when operation = 'buy' then qty else -qty end) over (order by id) as newstock
from t
```

Comment: Thank you for response. getting correct result. want to update something in above question.. there is one  more column avgprice (initial avgprice is 0)  so if operation is buy then (avgprice*newstock ) + (qty+price) and if operation is sale then avgprice is previous row avgprice. then how can compute it without loop'